# Cisco IOS - mapping out ports with arp, mac-address table, and interface status

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

I've unfortunately been tasked with determining which switchports connect to what- be it a connection to another switchport, or a link to a host. Basically determine what each port is connected to, for the entire core and distribution layer of this network topology.

To do this, I've gathered the following from each switch: switchport interface brief, mac-address table, arp results.

Trying to triangulate this information in my mind for each switch, see if it's first and access port or trunk, check the mac address table, see if any of those macs match the macs of the other switches, or anything in the arp table. This strategy has been very slow going and difficult to implement.

I'm wondering:
A) Is there a better way of doing this? Any tips or tricks anyone can provide to accomplish this goal?
B) are there any other command outputs, or information tables I am not utilizing that could possibly better equip me to figure this all out?
C) Anyone have any better ideas than what I'm doing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Cisco IOS, I recommend to use CDP (cisco discovery protocol) command for mapping your network.It's a proprietary protocol of cisco hence it will only identify cisco devices and connection of them. But this will come in handy for your work.

Cool!